# Youtube api cannot refresh access token

Tags: php, google-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-php-client, google-oauth

I previously had issue with the Google account to access Youtube's API. So i created a new fresh gmail account & managed to get it working. Not only after like One hour. I found out that Refresh Token wasn't refreshing. I don't know why. This is becoming frustrating as it seems i would have to forfeit using Youtube services any longer.

This is my code below: perhaps i'm doing something wrong.

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
    FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force'); // this line is important when you revoke permission from your app, it will prompt google approval dialogue box forcefully to user to grant offline access


// Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

// Check if an auth token exists for the required scopes
$tokenSessionKey = 'token-' . $client->prepareScopes();
$_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey] = $manually_stored_token; //$client->getAccessToken();



if (isset($_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey]);
}


// Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.
if($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {

          $client->refreshToken($refresh_token);
          if(!$client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
               // do something
          } else {
              // refresh access token not granted
          }


} else if ($client->getAccessToken()) {

    // do something

} else {
       // do something
}
```

I checked my account https://myaccount.google.com/u/0/security, under "Sign-in & Security" for authorized access to your Google Account, I still have authorization. So i don't know why its not refreshing my Token.

Comment: The client library should only be refreshing your access token when it needs to.  What makes you think its not?

Comment: I definitely know its not refreshing because i put break points to know when my token has Expired & then tries to refresh. This was working for like a week, until it just stopped. I didn't change anything, atleast that i know of !

Answer (score 0):

When you first authorise, you are given both the `access_token` and `refresh_token` in the response.
After that, you will only get a `access_token` back. 
The `refresh_token` you must save and re-use.

If for what ever reason you loose it, you must reset your authorise access.

I had this issue and had to make a dirty hack as no one could give me an answer.

Basic fix is to "un-authorise" a user and then "re-authorise" them again. As if you do not, you will never get the `refresh_token` back.

To test and inspect. Open your account that is being authorised.
Go into the Dashboard and find "Apps connected to your account" section.
There you will see your app and can manually remove it for testing.
However, you will need to code for this later, but is good enough for testing.